# Mapping @XmlAttribute in DOJO Class

Tags: java, javascript, json, rest, dojo

I have a Java object

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="Slot")
public class Slot {

@XmlAttribute(name="id")
private long id;

@XmlElement(name="type")
private String type;

//.. GETTERS AND SETTERS....
}
```

I need to get this **Slot** object from client side through REST(javax.ws.rs.GET) request.

When I create xml from above object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Slot id="123">
    <type>CHART</type>
</Slot>
```

and JSON is

```
{
   "Slot":{
      "@attributes":{
         "id":"123"
      },
      "type":"CHART"
   }
}
```

I need to create DOJO Class to hold data from UI which holds id and type values.

How can I represent **@attributes** in DOJO Class? Is there any programmatic way to achieve this? or we need to make it with JSON Stringify/something before server call to do this?

Comment: @attributes only in JSON not in XML for the same slot object?

Comment: Yes @RE350, It took from xml format itself.